# Como puedo acceder a los datos de un table html con js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Buenas Gente trato de acceder a los datos de esta tabla html en una vista de ASP.NET solo puedo acceder a los datos de una linea pero no puedo acceder a los datos de las demás filas del tbody, he tratado con varios métodos pero no logro acceder a los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando este Script para hacer la iteración de los elementos dentro de la tabla pero se me cae cuando trato de hacer la segunda iteración

```
<script>
$("#btnDatos").click(function () {

    'use strict'

  
    const tBody = document.getElementById('tableResultContent').children;
    for (let j = 0; j < tBody.length; j++) {
        const tablerow = tBody[j];
        console.log("Table Row = ", tablerow);
        for (let i = 0; i < tablerow.length; i++) {
            var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].innerHTML;
            console.log(td);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'ListarPedido',
                data: { listaPedido: td },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#txtListado").val(data.listadoFinal);
                }
            });
        }
    }

})
```

Codigo del Controlador que recibe la peticion del script

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ListarPedido(string listaPedido)
    {
        var listado = listaPedido.ToString();
        var listaPedidoViewModel = new PedidoViewModel()
        {
            NombrePedProducto = "Nombre",
            UnidadMedida = "Unidad",
            Precio = 10,//decimal
            Stock = 10,//decimal
            Cantidad = 10,//decimal
            Descuento = 10,//decimal
            Observacion = "Obs",
            Total = 10,//decimal

        };
        
        return Json(new { listaPedidoViewModel }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No repetir los id de las filas, los id deben ser únicos a nivel de página. Puedes dejarlo como clase

De esto:

```
<td class="c-table__cell" id="tdNombre">
```

Pasas a esto

```
<td class="c-table__cell tdNombre">
```

2. Tienes una llamada por Ajax en cada iteración. No entendí el motivo
3. Para buscar y recorrer las filas haces algo como esto:

```
let Datos = [];
document.querySelectorAll("#tableResultContent tr").forEach((fila) => { 
    let dato = {};
    dato.NombrePedProducto = fila.querySelector(".tdNombre").innerHTML;
    dato.UnidadMedida = fila.querySelector(".tdUnidad").innerHTML;
    dato.Precio = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdPrecio").innerHTML);
    dato.Stock = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdStock").innerHTML);
    dato.Cantidad = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdCantidad").innerHTML);
    dato.Descuento = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdDescuento").innerHTML);
    dato.Observacion = fila.querySelector(".tdObservacion").innerHTML;
    dato.Total = Number(fila.querySelector(".tdTotal").innerHTML);
  

    Datos.push(dato);
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ListarPedido',
    data: JSON.stringify(Datos),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
       
    }
});
```

Tu controlador debería ser algo como esto

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ListarPedido(List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedido)
    {
        //aquí alguna lógica, por ejemplo recorrerlo
        
        foreach(var i in listaPedido){
          Console.WriteLine(i.NombrePedProducto )
        }
        return Json(new { listaPedidoViewModel }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: es una tabla creada por javascript en donde los tr y td son creados en base a un script que ingresa los datos de un formulario

Comment: Realice lo que me dijiste y me llega null al controlador :c

Comment: Edita tu pregunta colocando el código del controlador y si el controlador recibe una clase, también agrégala

Comment: Hay agregue el controlador

Comment: basicamente debe retornar un json con los datos como se muestran pero como son varios debe ser una lista

Comment: Pero retornas los mismos datos que le enviaste?

Comment: no me llega los datos del script que envio el parametro listaPedido esta nulo en el controlador

Comment: Ahí edite, ve si con el nuevo código te llegan los datos

Comment: voy a probarlo te comento el resultado

Comment: em sigue llegando nulo

Comment: hice un cambio y funciono bro muchas gracias me sacaste de horas de quemarme las pestañas

Comment: Me alegro, recuerda aceptar la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Bro si puedes comentar el post para hacerte una pregunta con una duda sobre el codigo plis